# Errors Android Studio MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am coding MainActivity.java on Android Studio but I found that error

Cannot resolve symbol 'v7'

Here's my code:

```
/**
 * IMPORTANT: Make sure you are using the correct package name. 
 * This example uses the package name:
 * package com.example.android.justjava
 * If you get an error when copying this code into Android studio, update it to match teh package name found
 * in the project's AndroidManifest.xml file.
 **/

package com.example.android.justjava;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

Note: I am new to Android Studio

Best Regards

Also I have another errors:

Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'
Method does not override method from its superclass
Cannot resolve method 'onCreate(Bundle)'
Cannot resolve method 'setContentView' in 'MainActivity'
Cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in 'MainActivity'
Cannot resolve symbol 'quantity_text_view'
Unused import statement
Method 'onCreate(android.os.Bundle)' is never used
Method 'submitOrder(android.view.View)' is never used
Parameter 'view' is never used
Actual value of parameter 'number' is always '1'
Do not concatenate text displayed with `setText`. Use resource string with placeholders.
Empty string used in concatenation

Note: I am new to Android Studio

Best Regards,
Hamza Moustafa

Comment: can you please post your gradle file

Comment: As you are new, you can remove `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;` this line from your code, then Android Studio will show you an error, and by pressing alt+enter, Android Studio will automatically import it from the right package. If this doesn't work, you should post your gradle file then.